# Why does adding a face to QgsMeshLayer produce UniqueSharedVertex error?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, mesh

When creating a mesh, some faces are not added and return a `UniqueSharedVertex` error. I don't understand why this happens. Visually, it seems perfectly valid to add a face in the given location.

For example, in the mesh below, I can't add a triangular face between vertices [25, 51, 52].

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this?

QGIS version: 3.22.3

[image]

Code to reproduce issue:

```
from uuid import uuid4

from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsMesh, QgsMeshLayer, QgsPoint, QgsProject, QgsProviderRegistry, QgsProcessingUtils, QgsVectorLayer

ELEVATION_POINTS = [
    (91742.960662,439528.079357,0.5),
    (91733.92261,439529.209114,0.5),
    (91733.3684,439529.250096,0.5),
    (91732.812883,439529.234943,0.5),
    (91732.261731,439529.16381,0.5),
    (91731.72057,439529.037421,0.5),
    (91731.194926,439528.857069,0.5),
    (91730.690165,439528.624593,0.5),
    (91730.21144,439528.342368,0.5),
    (91729.763638,439528.013275,0.5),
    (91729.351332,439527.640673,0.5),
    (91727.851332,439526.140673,0.5),
    (91727.340419,439525.551586,0.5),
    (91725.840419,439523.551586,0.5),
    (91725.55606,439523.133735,0.5),
    (91725.311261,439522.691544,0.5),
    (91725.108087,439522.228748,0.5),
    (91724.948256,439521.749255,0.5),
    (91724.833117,439521.257114,0.5),
    (91724.763643,439520.756482,0.5),
    (91724.740419,439520.251586,0.5),
    (91724.740419,439516.218347,0.5),
    (91724.740419,439514.021549,0.5),
    (91724.740419,439511.275031,0.5),
    (91713.858254,439509.134278,0.5),
    (91742.836627,439527.08708,0),
    (91733.798575,439528.216836,0),
    (91733.345131,439528.250367,0),
    (91732.890617,439528.237969,0),
    (91732.439674,439528.179769,0),
    (91731.996906,439528.07636,0),
    (91731.566834,439527.928799,0),
    (91731.153847,439527.738592,0),
    (91730.762163,439527.507681,0),
    (91730.39578,439527.238422,0),
    (91730.058439,439526.933566,0),
    (91728.558439,439525.433566,0),
    (91728.140419,439524.951586,0),
    (91726.640419,439522.951586,0),
    (91726.407762,439522.609708,0),
    (91726.207471,439522.247915,0),
    (91726.041239,439521.869264,0),
    (91725.910468,439521.476951,0),
    (91725.816263,439521.074291,0),
    (91725.75942,439520.664683,0),
    (91725.740419,439520.251586,0),
    (91725.740419,439515.841793,0),
    (91725.740419,439514.021549,0),
    (91725.740419,439510.452587,0),
    (91725.413774,439510.388329,0),
    (91714.051276,439508.153083,0),
    (91741.720315,439518.156579,0),
    (91734.930691,439519.005282,0),
    (91734.740419,439518.751586,0),
    (91734.740419,439514.021549,0),
    (91734.740419,439513.087094,0),
    (91734.740419,439506.751586,0),
    (91734.718684,439506.309834,0),
    (91734.653688,439505.87235,0),
    (91734.54606,439505.443359,0),
    (91734.396839,439505.027006,0),
    (91734.207466,439504.627312,0),
    (91733.979772,439504.24814,0),
    (91733.715954,439503.89315,0),
    (91733.418563,439503.565774,0),
    (91733.090471,439503.269172,0),
    (91732.734847,439503.006211,0),
    (91732.355127,439502.779431,0),
    (91731.954978,439502.591022,0),
    (91731.538266,439502.442805,0),
    (91731.109017,439502.336211,0),
    (91727.150971,439501.557579,0),
    (91715.788472,439499.322333,0),
    (91741.59628,439517.164301,0.5),
    (91735.740419,439517.896283,0.5),
    (91735.740419,439514.021549,0.5),
    (91735.740419,439512.86109,0.5),
    (91735.740419,439506.751586,0.5),
    (91735.713854,439506.211667,0.5),
    (91735.634415,439505.676964,0.5),
    (91735.502869,439505.152642,0.5),
    (91735.320488,439504.643766,0.5),
    (91735.089032,439504.155252,0.5),
    (91734.810739,439503.691818,0.5),
    (91734.488296,439503.257942,0.5),
    (91734.124818,439502.857815,0.5),
    (91733.723816,439502.495303,0.5),
    (91733.289164,439502.173906,0.5),
    (91732.825062,439501.89673,0.5),
    (91732.335991,439501.666453,0.5),
    (91731.826677,439501.485298,0.5),
    (91731.302039,439501.355016,0.5),
    (91727.343993,439500.576384,0.5),
    (91715.981494,439498.341139,0.5)
]

triangles = {
    0: [0, 25, 1],
    1: [1, 25, 26],
    2: [1, 26, 27],
    3: [1, 27, 2],
    4: [2, 27, 28],
    5: [2, 28, 3],
    6: [3, 28, 29],
    7: [3, 29, 4],
    8: [4, 29, 30],
    9: [4, 30, 5],
    10: [5, 30, 31],
    11: [5, 31, 32],
    12: [5, 32, 6],
    13: [6, 32, 33],
    14: [6, 33, 7],
    15: [7, 33, 34],
    16: [7, 34, 8],
    17: [8, 34, 35],
    18: [8, 35, 9],
    19: [9, 35, 10],
    20: [10, 35, 36],
    21: [10, 36, 37],
    22: [10, 37, 11],
    23: [11, 37, 12],
    24: [12, 37, 38],
    25: [12, 38, 39],
    26: [12, 39, 40],
    27: [12, 40, 13],
    28: [13, 40, 41],
    29: [13, 41, 14],
    30: [14, 41, 42],
    31: [14, 42, 15],
    32: [15, 42, 43],
    33: [15, 43, 44],
    34: [15, 44, 16],
    35: [16, 44, 45],
    36: [16, 45, 17],
    37: [17, 45, 18],
    38: [18, 45, 19],
    39: [19, 45, 20],
    40: [20, 45, 46],
    41: [20, 46, 21],
    42: [21, 46, 47],
    43: [21, 47, 22],
    44: [22, 47, 48],
    45: [22, 48, 49],
    46: [22, 49, 23],
    47: [23, 49, 50],
    48: [23, 50, 24],
    49: [25, 51, 52],
    50: [25, 52, 26],
    51: [26, 52, 53],
    52: [26, 53, 27],
    53: [27, 53, 28],
    54: [28, 53, 29],
    55: [29, 53, 30],
    56: [30, 53, 31],
    57: [31, 53, 32],
    58: [32, 53, 33],
    59: [33, 53, 54],
    60: [33, 54, 34],
    61: [34, 54, 35],
    62: [35, 54, 55],
    63: [35, 55, 36],
    64: [36, 55, 37],
    65: [37, 55, 38],
    66: [38, 55, 39],
    67: [39, 55, 40],
    68: [40, 55, 41],
    69: [41, 55, 42],
    70: [42, 55, 56],
    71: [42, 56, 43],
    72: [43, 56, 57],
    73: [43, 57, 44],
    74: [44, 57, 58],
    75: [44, 58, 45],
    76: [45, 58, 59],
    77: [45, 59, 60],
    78: [45, 60, 61],
    79: [45, 61, 62],
    80: [45, 62, 63],
    81: [45, 63, 64],
    82: [45, 64, 65],
    83: [45, 65, 66],
    84: [45, 66, 67],
    85: [45, 67, 68],
    86: [45, 68, 46],
    87: [46, 68, 69],
    88: [46, 69, 70],
    89: [46, 70, 47],
    90: [47, 70, 71],
    91: [47, 71, 48],
    92: [48, 71, 49],
    93: [49, 71, 72],
    94: [49, 72, 50],
    95: [51, 73, 74],
    96: [51, 74, 52],
    97: [52, 74, 53],
    98: [53, 74, 75],
    99: [53, 75, 76],
    100: [53, 76, 54],
    101: [54, 76, 55],
    102: [55, 76, 77],
    103: [55, 77, 78],
    104: [55, 78, 79],
    105: [55, 79, 80],
    106: [55, 80, 56],
    107: [56, 80, 81],
    108: [56, 81, 57],
    109: [57, 81, 58],
    110: [58, 81, 82],
    111: [58, 82, 59],
    112: [59, 82, 83],
    113: [59, 83, 60],
    114: [60, 83, 84],
    115: [60, 84, 61],
    116: [61, 84, 85],
    117: [61, 85, 62],
    118: [62, 85, 63],
    119: [63, 85, 86],
    120: [63, 86, 64],
    121: [64, 86, 87],
    122: [64, 87, 65],
    123: [65, 87, 88],
    124: [65, 88, 66],
    125: [66, 88, 89],
    126: [66, 89, 67],
    127: [67, 89, 68],
    128: [68, 89, 90],
    129: [68, 90, 69],
    130: [69, 90, 91],
    131: [69, 91, 70],
    132: [70, 91, 92],
    133: [70, 92, 71],
    134: [71, 92, 93],
    135: [71, 93, 72]
}

# Create mesh
provider_meta = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('mdal')
mesh = QgsMesh()
temp_mesh_filename = f"{uuid4()}.nc"
temp_mesh_fullpath = QgsProcessingUtils.generateTempFilename(temp_mesh_filename)
mesh_format = 'Ugrid'
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
provider_meta.createMeshData(mesh, temp_mesh_fullpath, mesh_format, crs)
mesh_layer = QgsMeshLayer(temp_mesh_fullpath, 'my_mesh', 'mdal')

# add points to mesh
transform = QgsCoordinateTransform()
mesh_layer.startFrameEditing(transform)
editor = mesh_layer.meshEditor()
points = [QgsPoint(x, y, z) for x, y, z in ELEVATION_POINTS]
points_added = editor.addPointsAsVertices(points, 0.0000001)
for vertex_indices in triangles.values():
    error = editor.addFace(vertex_indices)
    if error.errorType != 0:
        print(error.errorType)
        print(error.elementIndex)
mesh_layer.commitFrameEditing(transform, continueEditing=False)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mesh_layer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mesh editing, some topological rules have to be respected. One of them is the impossibility that two faces share only one vertices. This error `uniqueSharedVertex` comes from here. To avoid this error you have to take care of the order of added faces. In this case, another solution could to add a face with 4 vertices and then split it.